# Given 10 people: $P_1, P_2, \ldots,P_{10}$ how many 6-member teams can be formed if

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> Given 10 people $P_1, P_2, \ldots,P_{10}$  how many 6-member  teams can be formed if at most one of $P_2, P_4$ can be chosen?

Either one of P2 or P4 gives 8c5 ways to choose.
My answer is:
$$
{8\choose5} + {8\choose5} + {8\choose6} = 140
$$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: the answer is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Another method of doing the problem is to subtract those selections in which both $P_2$ and $P_4$ are selected from the total number of $6$-member teams which could be formed from the $10$ people.  There are $\binom{10}{6}$ ways to select six of the ten people.  If both $P_2$ and $P_4$ were selected, we would have to select four of the other $10 - 2 = 8$ people.  Hence, the number of $6$-members teams which include at most one of $P_2$ and $P_4$ is
$$\binom{10}{6} - \binom{2}{2}\binom{8}{4} = 210 - 70 = 140$$
as you found by a direct count.